# VS For Mac error generating android build - NDK

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild

I installed Visual Studio for Mac and around to build the application for Android it gave me this error. I installed NDK and now this error appears to me.

Do you know how to solve this?

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2873,3): error XA5101: C compiler for target Arm was not found. Tried paths: "/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc; /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/gcc" [/Users/UserName/Projetos/ProjectName/app/src/android/ProjectNameApp.Droid/ProjectName.Droid.csproj]

An error occurred when executing task 'Release-Android'.
Teardown
Executing custom teardown action...
Environment: QA
Configuration: Release
Target: Release-Android
Error: One or more errors occurred. (MSBuild: Process returned an error (exit code 1).)
MSBuild: Process returned an error (exit code 1).

I have already seen several solutions but I can not solve it, I have already installed NDK, I have already validated the folder where it is installed, I have already inserted AndroidNdkDirectory in Droid.csproj and so far none of this has resulted.

[image: I have already installed NDK]
[image: I have already validated the folder where it is installed]
[image: I have already validated the folder where it is installed]
[image: I have already inserted AndroidNdkDirectory in Droid.csproj]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two potential ways to resolve this issue:

- You can switch the Android NDK version to r17 or lower. One way to do that is to un-check **NDK** from the Android SDK manager (the **Tools** tab from your screenshot) to uninstall version r19, then select the gear icon from the lower right of the window, pick the **Microsoft (Recommended)** repository, and check **NDK** version r17 (which should now appear in the list) to install that version.
- Or, if you are working on code where you can use a preview version of Xamarin.Android, you can update to the current preview Xamarin.Android version 9.3.0.19 by switching to the **Preview** [updater channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/mac/update) in Visual Studio for Mac.

**Additional info**

The current Xamarin.Android SDK version 9.2.3.0 is not yet compatible with Android NDK versions r18 or higher, where [GCC has been removed](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18).

Compatibility with those newer NDK versions (and in particular, compatibility with the change from `gcc` to `clang`) is [included in the preview Xamarin.Android SDK version 9.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.3#android-ndk-r19-compatibility).

Comment: For anyone wanting to download the older NDK directly: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html